# Find a graph when given length-k paths?

Tags: graph-theory

I have an undirected connected graph $G$ and I have a matrix $S^{(k)}$ were $S^{(k)}_{i,j}=1$ if  there is a length-$k$ path between $i$ and $j$ and 0 otherwise. Now, $S^{(1)}$ is then simply the adjacency matrix, which uniquely defines my graph.  Is it possible to compute a graph (not necessarily unique) $G$ from $S^{(2)}$ or any other $S^{(k)}$, $k>1$?

Comment: There are non-complete graphs where each pair of vertices is connected with a length 2 path.

Comment: Also, if in a graph of 3 vertices $S^{(2)}_{12}=S^{(2)}_{13}=1$, then necessarily $S^{(2)}_{23}=1$, so there are non-trivial restrictions. Should we understand the question as "Assuming that $S^{(k)}$ is feasible, how to find an underlying graph efficiently?" instead?

Comment: Yes, "how to find efficiently", ideally in polynomial time, but I would of course be interested in approximate solutions and inefficient methods that might point the way to better avenues.

Comment: Ilya said that $S^{(2)}$ might tell you nothing about $G$.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik It might also tell you something, correct? I can see "remove one edge from a complete graph" resulting in  the same $S^{(2)}$ regardless of the edge removed, but this seems like a pathological case?

Comment: any diameter 2 graph with a triangle on each edge will have a trivial $S^{(2)}$. and there are lots of such graphs out there.

Comment: Does this make it possible for a given $S^{(2)}$ to construct the associated graph? That is, is there a trivial solution for a given $S^{(2)}$?